# How to insert nested entities using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Assume we have an `Invoice` entity which has many `InvoiceDetails`.

Each invoice detail has `InvoiceId` as FK.

How can I insert an `Invoice` and its' `InvoiceDetails` using Entity Framework using minimal db connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF uses this way:

```
context.Invoices.Add(invoice); // invoice contains all invoice details 
context.SaveChanges();
```

It will use single database connection but each entity will be inserted in separate database roundtrip because EF doesn't support command batching.

Comment: Thank you Lidislav. How about Invoice.InvoiceDetails? How about InvoiceDetail.InvoiceId? Does EF handle it perfectly?

Comment: EF will handle it without any problem if you have relations correctly mapped and `InvoiceId` is mapped as FK for the relation.